# Run Click After SetTimeout Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click through various buttons in a survey.

At the moment, I have the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery('.gform_next_button[tabindex="1"]').click();}, 3000);
     });
</script>
```

I would like the code to click the element with class `".gform_next_button"` and `tabindex = 1` **once** only. **How can I use the .one() function to run this only once?**

Answer (score 0):

Store the index you want in a variable outside of the `setTimeout` callback. Increment it and concatenate it with the selector string inside of the callback.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function() {
        var index = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            jQuery(`.gform_next_button[tabindex="${index}"]`).click();
            index++;
        }, 3000);
    })();
});
```

I also converted it to `setInterval` since that will cause a loop.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this, preferably with the code I posted? I'm a beginner. I also don't want all the clicks to have the same time out value (ie, 3000 milliseconds). Some will have 5 minutes between them, so I really think wrapping the function in a way that it runs once and doing it manually would serve my purposes better.

Comment: OK! I tried this @daniel-a-white. Unfortunately the tabindex rules don't follow a single adding pattern. Could I list in this code the order of the tabindex values to follow, instead of simply adding (n+1)?

Comment: sure - you could use an array as a lookup mechanism.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't select the next value in the array I've listed. What am I doing wrong? Could you also show me a basic way to just wrap the function I wrote in a way that it runs only once?

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function() {
        var tabs = [1,6,8,13,15,20,22,27,29,34,36,41];
        var index = tabs[0]
        setInterval(function(){
            jQuery(`.gform_next_button[tabindex="${index}"]`).click();
            index++;
        }, 3000);
    })();
});

Comment: use `index = 0` and look it up inside of the function.

Comment: Hi Daniel! OK thanks for all of your help. I really just want to use the .one() function somehow with my code to fire it once, and only once. Could you help me with adjusting my code to do that?

Comment: @2567655222 `.one` is for handling an event one time, not firing events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169464/discussion-between-2567655222-and-daniel-a-white).